# How to fix double data entry into excel file

Tags: python, tkinter

When the GUI is used while the excel file is blank, save for header, it will insert the information twice. Then, during consecutive runs it will no longer insert into the excel file.

Changed master.quit to master.destroy

```
import pandas as pd

def submit_fields():
    path = 'C:\Python32\RequestForm.xlsx'
    df1 = pd.read_excel(path)
    SeriesA = df1['Name']
    SeriesB = df1['Reason']
    SeriesC = df1['startDate']
    SeriesC = df1['endDate']
    A = pd.Series(entry1.get())
    B = pd.Series(entry2.get())
    C = pd.Series(entry3.get())
    D = pd.Series(entry4.get())
    SeriesA = SeriesA.append(A)
    SeriesB = SeriesB.append(B)
    SeriesC = SeriesC.append(C)
    SeriesD = SeriesD.append(D)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":SeriesA, "Reason":SeriesB, "startDate":SeriesC, "endDate":SeriesD})
    df2.to_excel(path, index=False)
    entry1.delete(0, END)
    entry2.delete(0, END)
    entry3.delete(0, END)
    entry4.delete(0, END)

master = Tk()
master.geometry('250x250')
master.title("Request Form")

Label(master, text="Name").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Reason").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Start Date").grid(row=2)
Label(master, text="End Date").grid(row=3)


entry1 = Entry(master)
entry2 = Entry(master)
entry3 = Entry(master)
entry4 = Entry(master)

entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=4)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=4)
entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=4)
entry4.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=4)


Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.destroy).grid(row=4,column=0, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Submit', command=submit_fields).grid(row=4,column=1, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Expected results are one row should be populated with the information from the data entry GUI. And should work when GUI reopened and used.
Actual results, works the first time but doubles the insert. Will not work after first time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KRl9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Copy paste got me.

```
 SeriesA = df1['Name']
    SeriesB = df1['Reason']
    SeriesC = df1['startDate']
    **SeriesC** = df1['endDate']
```